# The "I'm Done" button in first posts review turns clickable even if we haven't reviewed!

Tags: discussion, bug

Recently I have come across a first posts review case wherein if a user accidentally applies a close vote to a post and then retracts it, the I'm done button turns clickable. Is this expected? Because we still haven't reviewed the post.

In this case if we click “I'm done” does it count towards “no action needed” situation(because we havn’t done anything to be qualified for “I'm done” )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta.  Or in other words, people may disagree that its a bug.  Either that, or they are unable to reproduce.

Comment: My question is that, in this case if we click “i’m done” does it count towards “no action needed” situation(because we havn’t done anything to be qualified for “i’m done” )

Comment: And as said, they may disagree with your premise.  That doesn't require an answer.

Comment: Yes they sure can, and please don't get me wrong- i have no problem with downvotes or users disagreeing with the post.  But i still don’t understand whether it does not qualify as a bug or that it could not be reproduced

Answer (score -1):

It takes **at least three clicks in different areas** to cast a close vote.

I do not see it happening *"accidentally"*.

If you've casted a CV, you've reviewed the post. It's then fine to enable the *I'm done* button.

If you change your mind, well, you've still reviewed the post. It only you took a lot of effort to end up with a null situation, and the CV retraction doesn't count as coming from withing review.

You can still use all the other review options (voting, commenting, flagging, editing).

Disabling that button is only there to remind you that **some** action is expected. But you could always skip the review anyway.

All in all, not a bug for me. I guess some additional logic could be added to catch this situation, but the added complexity doesn't seem particulary useful for such a corner case.

Discounting the far-fetched argument of someone close-voting "accidentally", a user who CVs and later retracts is still spending a fair amount of time and energy reviewing the post.

Comment: totally agree with you on this, but the issue is that the review count is getting added up. So we can just make the review count go up by first doing CV and then retracting it. If we "skip", the review count does not increase. Further, based on review counts users get awarded badges as well. So will they be using it just to increase their review count?

Comment: It's quite a bit of work "just to increase their review count". Easier to upvote everything you encounter, and if you really, really want check the post outside the review queue and undo your upvote. Again, the CV retraction happens out-of-sequence, it's not considered to happen within the review action. No bug nor a something that needs changing, IMO.

Comment: but will blindly up-voting everything lead to a review block(asking you to be careful while reviewing)?

Comment: Hopefully a user that attempted doing that would end up review banned, yes. Close voting everything to later retact your vote, as well. So I do not understand your concern. You are the one that brought up doing stuff in review to raise your review count.